# Convert object with java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have this 2 object:

```
public class Service {
    private String cod;
    private String name;
    private String table;
    private String selo;
    private BigDecimal value;
    private BigDecimal desconto;
    private BigDecimal baseCalculo;
    private Integer amountExcedente;
    private String descontoLei;

... G and S
}
```

And

```
    public class ServiceResumo {
        private String name;
        private int amount;
        private BigDecimal value;
        private String acao;

        public ServiceResumo(String name, BigDecimal value, int amount) {
            this.name = name;
            this.value = value;
            this.amount = amount;
        }
    ...G and S
    }
```

So I have a lot of Service,

```
List<Service> servicos = new ArrayList<Service>();
servicos.add(new Service("Service A", 3,.....)); //Service A -> Name and 3 -> value
servicos.add(new Service("Service B", 4.....));
servicos.add(new Service("Service A", 2,.....));
servicos.add(new Service("Service C", 3,.....));
servicos.add(new Service("Service D", 5,.....));
servicos.add(new Service("Service A", 6,.....));
servicos.add(new Service("Service A", 8,.....));
servicos.add(new Service("Service B", 9, .....));
```

So can I using stream in java 8 reduce this to a List of ServiceResumo? somethign like this:

|  name   | value |  amount |

Service A |  21   |     4       |

Service B |  13   |     2       |

Service C |   3   |     1       |

Service D |   5   |     1       |

Comment: Hint: in the future, try to write your programs using english words, it is easier to understand for others!

Comment: Sorry for my wrong answer before. If you want to group the `Servico`, you should state that in your question (please edit question if so)!

Comment: no problem, I change the words to English, to be more specific :D

Comment: How do you get the value `21` for `ServiceA`? When summing, I’ll get `19`…

Comment: sorry @Holger u r correct :D

Answer (score 2):

You get the desired result by combining three collectors

- There’s a built-in collector, `groupingBy`, which allows to group the elements by a property like the name.
- In order to aggregate the groups into a `ServicoResumo` object, you need a collector capable of aggregating the `Service` instances into such a `ServicoResumo` instance. You have to create a custom collector for that.
- Since the result of combining the `groupingBy` collector with your custom collector will be `Map<PropertyType,AggregationResult>`, i.e. `Map<String,ServicoResumo>`, you need a post-processing step to convert it to a `List<ServicoResumo>`, which can be done via `collectingAndThen`

```
List<ServiceResumo> result=servicos.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Service::getName,
            Collector.of(()->new ServiceResumo(null, BigDecimal.ZERO, 0),
                (r,s) -> {
                    r.setName(s.getName());
                    r.setValue(r.getValue().add(s.getValue()));
                    r.setAmount(r.getAmount()+1);
                },
                (r1,r2) -> {
                    r1.setValue(r1.getValue().add(r2.getValue()));
                    r1.setAmount(r1.getAmount()+r2.getAmount());
                    return r1;
                })),
            m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())
    ));
```

The first argument to `groupingBy`, `Service::getName` specifies the property that makes up the grouping criteria. The second argument to `collectingAndThen`, `m -> new ArrayList<>(m.values())`, tells how to convert the `Map` to the desired `List`.

The big part in-between, is the custom collector created via `Collector.of`. Refer to the [`Collector` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Collector.html) or the [“Mutable Reduction” section of the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) to learn how collectors work.